# Rspec: how to access other database in a test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rspec2

In my **Rspec** test, I need to creat some tables to **another database** instead of the app's test database, how to do it?

Basically, in my **Rspec test**, inside  `before(:all)`, I would like to execute SQL from a dump file which creates tables to **another database**.

But when I run my Rspec test, it creates all tables in the test database (which is understandable since it is in the Rspec test of the app.)

So, how to run sql to create tables to **another databse** in my Rspec test code?

Answer (score 0):

All tests are run in the Rails test environment. Any SQL performed here is constrained to the test environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can access whatever db you want with:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  :adapter  => 'mysql2',
  :database => 'db_name',
  :username => 'root',
  :password => '',
  :host     => 'localhost')
```

Of course the hash could be changed. I never tried what you expect though. I think you should reconnect to your test db once your other call has been done.